# i want to create the non-web spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

i want to create the non-web spring boot application. But i am getting following error

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        taskService.print();

    }

}

public interface TaskService  {

    public void print();
}



public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("sam");
    }

}
```

properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
##spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field taskService in com.example.task.TaskApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.task.service.TaskService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Action:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.task.service.TaskService' in your configuration.

Comment: Your `TaskServiceImpl` should be annotated with `@Service` or `@Component` to be detected.

Answer (score 2):

@M. Deinum already explained in comments. You need to mark classes with `@Service` or `@Component` annotation to create the spring bean and autowired in main methods.

```
    // mark it with service annotation.
    @Service
    public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("sam");
        }

    }
```

To understand why those annotation is necessary here please visit this link :  [@Component vs @Repository and @Service in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service)

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure @EnableAutoConfiguration on main class and your TaskService must be annotated with @Service

Comment: `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is already implied through `@SpringBootApplication` so no need to add that.